# How to send ETH to a contract function with ethers.js?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I am trying to send ETH to a contract function from a web app via metamask and ethers.js. So far I have tried:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const splitterManager = new ethers.Contract(contract.address, contract.abi, signer);
var overrides = {value: 5}
const result = await splitterManager.newSplitter(addresses, shares, erc20, overrides);
console.log(result);
```

But I keep getting 'Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name (argument="name", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.2.0)'.

Answer (score 10):

You can call the contracts function and pass it an object containing a `value` key.

```js
contractInstance.testFunction(<any function args>, { value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "ether") });
```

This would call your contract's function and send that amount of wei to the contract.

```
function testFunction() public payable {
    // contract code
}
```

Comment: Note can do `ethers.utils.parseEther("1")`

Answer (score 5):

If the contract has implemented the [receive function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html#receive-ether-function), you can send ether to a contract same as sending ether to any other account. Here's a short example:

```js
const accounts = await provider.listAccounts();
const signer = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);
tx = {
    to: **CONTRACT_ADDRESS**,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther('2', 'ether')
};
const transaction = await signer.sendTransaction(tx);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
await contractInstance
  .connect(rpcProvider)
  .function({
    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1","ether")
  });
```

this should work

Answer (score -1):

some address is an invalid address it could be the contract.address, the addresses, or some other address